# How to end a process in another linux terminal

Tags: linux, process, kill, framebuffer, sigterm

**Background Info:**

- I'm trying to set up a remote display using a raspberry pi.
- Currently I'm using fbi (frame buffer image viewer) to display the image.
- The device is going to be controlled via ssh or web interface - not sure which, but definitely not from the actual device.

**The Problem** is I cant seem to find an easy way to "clean" quit the process remotely, clear the screen & generate no errors. The fbi program will exit if the q button is pressed but that seems to do no good over ssh. Ideally I'd prefer a less messy solution then having to look up the pid each time before killing it. I am open to the idea of using another program, however I can't run it in Xorg.

**I've tried:**

- Grep-ing the pid and sending `kill -sigterm` but it either doesn't quit or doesnt clear the screen
- `echo "q" > /proc/[pid]/fd/0`  - all the iterations i try I either get an access denied or nothing happens

Any Ideas?

Comment: SUGGESTION: I'd write a shell script that 1) does a "kill -9 fbi", then 2) calls "clear"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to kill a process without a message?
In one terminal, I started a process:

```
# sleep 100
```

Now to kill the process, without a message and without knowing the pid:

```
# kill -13 (pgrep sleep)
```

How to remotely clear the screen of a terminal?
First, get the tty # of the terminal you want to clear:

```
# tty
/dev/pts/1
```

Now from a different terminal:

```
# printf '\033c' > /dev/pts/1
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, a solution could be to use fbi to just display an image on fb0 from another terminal:

```
fbi -T 1 -noverbose -d /dev/fb0 image.png
```

Then just clear the entire framebuffer (fb0):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fb0
```

Or better yet, just write a "blank" image to fb0 to "clear" it.